# 'a sense of' before two nouns in a sentence

Tags: grammar

May I ask if I would like to say someone is responsible and disciplined, can I put it as:

1. He has a sense of responsibility and discipline.

or I need to put it as:

2. He has the senses of responsibility and discipline.

Many thanks!!

Comment: Do you regard "responsibility and discipline" to be a single attribute or two distinct attributes?  (May be context-dependent.)

Comment: Two distinct attributes. So if they are regarded as a single attribute in the discussion, then I can put it as 'a sense of responsibility and discipline'? If discussing them as two distinct attributes, then I need to say 'the senses of responsibility and discipline'? right?

Comment: I perceive *"a sense of ..."* as one of those nouns that can only be singular. So: *"He has a sense of responsibility and of discipline."* [Some Ngrams evidence for my view.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=their+sense+of+humor%2C+their+senses+of+humor&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctheir%20sense%20of%20humor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctheir%20senses%20of%20humor%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Why not say it as you've already said it--responsible and disciplined?

Comment: Just hoped to clear up the confusion about the usage of the phrase 'a sense of'..so I can use varied phrases in my writings..thanks:]

Answer (score 1):

The [Cambridge Learner's Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/learner-english/sense_1) says that this meaning of sense cannot be pluralized<sup>1</sup>:

> ABILITY [ no plural ]
>   ​the ability to do something:
>   *a sense of direction
>
>   good business sense*

So you should say

> a sense of responsibility and discipline,

or if you want to convey the notion that these are two different things, you can say

> a sense of responsibility and of discipline.

<sup>1</sup> The closely related meaning of the *senses of smell, taste, touch, etc.* can be pluralized.

Answer (score 0):

He has a sense of responsibility and discipline.

'sense' can be used because here both can be interdependent and thought of as one collective attribute without undermining the importance of any.